# I am practicing a message app. I stored it in firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a flutter app and storing the Text inside message in FIRESTORE. But the problem here is, When i type a message and press the onTap it store the message in the firestore but the streambuilder doesn't update the text in the chronological order. What to with this?

Here is the message gets updated

```
 Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      MessageStream(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

onTap funtion add the text inside firestore

```
GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _messageTextController.clear();
                        if (messageTyped.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                          _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                            'Text': messageTyped,
                            'Sender': loggedInUser.email,
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 2.2 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier), //8
                        width: 13.88 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                        height: 7.44 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.send,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

MessageStream stl widget

```
class MessageStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageSender = message.data()['Sender'];
          final messageText = message.data()['Text'];
          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            text: messageText,
            sender: messageSender,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `dateCreated` field when saving messages:

```
_firestore.collection('messages').add({
  'Text': messageTyped,
  'Sender': loggedInUser.email,
  'dateCreated': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

Then use `dateCreated` to order stream results:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _firestore.collection('messages')
   .orderBy('dateCreated', descending: false)
   .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
   ...
 },
)
```